# Sync music to Ubuntu One from media server?

Tags: ubuntu-one

My music collection is stored on a media server (11.04 + MythTV). My `~/Music` folder is mapped to a NFS share on the media server, but Ubuntu One will not synchronize to the mapped drive (probably no surprise there). Nor is the music folder located under a home/ folder on the server (it's `/var/lib/mythtv/music`).

So, how to synchronize the music with Ubuntu One and thereby access it for mobile streaming? Perhaps install Ubuntu One on the server, move the music to `~/Music` and sync it, and then symlink it from `/var/lib/mythtv` (I like to use the Myth player on the media system)? Opinions?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, NFS does not support inotify, which is likely used heavily for filesync with Ubuntu One. I also seem to remember that Ubuntu One doesn't sync files and folders from outside your home directory.

Your suggestion sounded best to me. Do I get an upvote for that? :)

Comment: I'm fairly sure that you can also configure MythTV's folder to be ~/Music rather than /var/lib/mythtv if you preferred it that way rather than a symlink. The idea sounds good to me, though!